# Using 4d variable inside a query in quick report editor

Tags: 4d-database, 4d

I'm creating a 4qr quick report file, and I am wondering how I can use a variable in a query inside the quick report editor.

Answer (score 0):

Double-click the column header with the field name. Then you get an editor.

Peter

Comment: Thank you for your input, the problem was to include a variable in the said editor.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should disable "Filtering command" option in Security settings page of Database Settings, because the Query is not available in the usually reduced set of commands for every user (a query inside a report could change the current selection of reported table, for example)

After, in Formula Editor you can write an expression as
`QUERY([Table_1];[Table_1]field1=Variable)`